# Mysql Master-Slave Replication Grant privileges to salve error

Tags: mysql

sql:

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO root@'172.17.0.5' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'root123';
```

Error Info:

> [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'root123'' at line 1

Answer (score -1):

I thik it's helpful for you.

`GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'root'@'172.17.0.5' IDENTIFIED BY 'root123';`

Comment: This doesn't work, I'm still getting same error.